# libbtc: Where are the binaries generated?

Tags: library, c

I installed and compiled libbtc from https://github.com/libbtc/libbtc, but where are the binaries generated or how can I compile my C project with gcc using it?

My OS is Ubuntu 20.04.
I am running:

- ./autogen.sh
- ./configure
- make
- sudo make install
- sudo make check

But when I run make check, it never ends.

```
EDIT: make check resulted ./build-aux/test-driver, linha 107: 18325 Segmentation fault (core dumped) "$@" > $log_file 2>&1
FAIL: tests
============================================================================
Testsuite summary for libbtc 0.1
============================================================================
# TOTAL: 1
# PASS:  0
# SKIP:  0
# XFAIL: 0
# FAIL:  1
# XPASS: 0
# ERROR: 0
============================================================================
See ./test-suite.log
Please report to https://github.com/jonasschnelli/libbtc/issues
============================================================================
```

Comment: this is a grait question, but we need to know the OS and the command that you are running, in other words, we need you know if you run make install, or you run only the make command. If you are using Cmake inside your app and you are not found the library that you installed, you need to require it. But it is another question for another forum.

Comment: @vincenzopalazzo My OS is Ubuntu 20.04.
I am running:
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
sudo make install
sudo make check
But when I run make check, it never ends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How the console tells, maybe this is not the correct place, also because you receive a `segmentation fault (core dumped)` during the make check.

> See ./test-suite.log
> Please report to https://github.com/jonasschnelli/libbtc/issues

However, may you have installed the library in your system with the command `sudo make install`, this command puts the binaries of the library is a place where are all the libraries of the system?
Maybe you have only a failure in the check

But the last commit of this library is on Nov 4, 2018, and maybe this can be a signal of the motivation of your error.

I hope I clarify your idea

Comment: Thanks! It worked! I just used -lbtc!

Comment: @Papaulo if you accept my edit on the question, we make the question more readble

Comment: @vicenzopalazzo I accepted, and now it's better, thanks, but I've got another error: "error while loading shared libraries: libbtc.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory" when running my program. I think I will make another question.

Comment: I don't know if it is good open a new question, the problem is related to a failure of the install process

Comment: This question is old, and it's another failure.

Comment: @vincenzopallazo Oh, I solved this problem.